# Jenkins Maven build reports success despite failed unit test

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.2.3, JUnit 4.12, and SureFire 2.18.1 within Jenkins.  I have a multi-module Maven job set up with the following Maven options:

```
clean install -U -e -P qa -Dci -DskipITs
```

However, when I run my Maven build, although one of my JUnit tests fail, the Maven module itself reports "SUCCESS" (output after) ...

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/pom.xml clean install -U -e -P qa -Dci -DskipITs


…

———————————————————————————
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.mainco.subco.user.domain.UserTest
Tests run: 24, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.049 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.mainco.subco.user.domain.UserTest
testHasRoleNullRoles(org.mainco.subco.user.domain.UserTest)  Time elapsed: 0.006 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to indicate we found right role for user.
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at 

…

[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ othersubmodule ---
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/othersubmodule/target/othersubmodule.war to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/mainco/subco/othersubmodule/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/othersubmodule-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/othersubmodule/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/mainco/subco/othersubmodule/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/othersubmodule-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] subco ....................................... SUCCESS [4.849s]
[INFO] database .......................................... SUCCESS [18.340s]
[INFO] session ........................................... SUCCESS [6.601s]
[INFO] main .............................................. SUCCESS [8:00.887s]
[INFO] mainclient ........................................ SUCCESS [4:01.490s]
[INFO] orders ............................................ SUCCESS [50.831s]
[INFO] SBD myproject Webapp .................................. SUCCESS [1:45.484s]
[INFO] subco Admin Module .......................... SUCCESS [1:01.318s]
[INFO] Other Submodule ................................ SUCCESS [6.162s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16:20.351s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 20 21:17:57 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 76M/748M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/orgsclient/pom.xml to org.mainco.subco/orgsclient/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/orgsclient-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/orgsclient/target/orgsclient.war to org.mainco.subco/orgsclient/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/orgsclient-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/pom.xml to org.mainco.subco/subco/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/subco-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/myproject/pom.xml to org.mainco.subco/myproject/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/myproject-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/myproject/target/myproject.war to org.mainco.subco/myproject/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/myproject-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/database/pom.xml to org.mainco.subco/database/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/database-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/database/target/database-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to org.mainco.subco/database/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/database-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/othersubmodule/pom.xml to org.mainco.subco/othersubmodule/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/othersubmodule-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/othersubmodule/target/othersubmodule.war to org.mainco.subco/othersubmodule/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/othersubmodule-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/sbadmin/pom.xml to org.mainco.subco/sbadmin/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/sbadmin-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/sbadmin/target/sbadmin.war to org.mainco.subco/sbadmin/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/sbadmin-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/main/pom.xml to org.mainco.subco/main/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/main-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/main/target/main.jar to org.mainco.subco/main/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/main-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/main/target/main-tests.jar to org.mainco.subco/main/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/main-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/orders/pom.xml to org.mainco.subco/orders/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/orders-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/orders/target/orders.jar to org.mainco.subco/orders/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/orders-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/session/pom.xml to org.mainco.subco/session/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/session-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/session/target/session.jar to org.mainco.subco/session/83.0.0-SNAPSHOT/session-83.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Sending e-mails to: sb-engineers@evotext.com laura.curry@evotext.com deb.arsenault@evotext.com bob.bean@evotext.com laredotornado@live.com
```

channel stopped
    Sending e-mails to: list@myco.com
    Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
    Finished: UNSTABLE

How do I get the Maven module to report FAILURE if one of the unit tests fails?  I realize the overall build reports as UNSTABLE in Jenkins, but for readability, i would prefer SUCCESS to show only if everything passed.

**Edit:** Here is the surefire plugin configuration

```
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.18.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                                    <argLine>-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -noverify -XX:-UseSplitVerifier ${argLine}</argLine>
                                    <skipTests>${skipAllTests}</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

Comment: So you get Unstable and you want Failure, is that correct?

Comment: I think he wants maven to fail the build instead of showing success. Out of curiosity, have you tried manually setting the test failure ignore (http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) property to false?

Comment: Hi, I want what spoonybard896 described -- the Maven build to fail instead of showing success.  I haven't set the property you mention explicitly.  Including my surefire config in case that adds any clarity to this.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing your whole setup. Have you actually verified that the maven.test.failure.ignore user property is false?

Comment: This can only be set by the plugin, right?  Is there a way to output what this value is as Maven runs, (e.g. adding "-X" or somethign similar)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Jenkins build fail when Maven unit tests fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683518/how-do-i-make-jenkins-build-fail-when-maven-unit-tests-fail)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer is basically what @spoonybard896 suggested in a comment.

Add `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false` to `MAVEN_OPTS`. That can be added in the Build -> Advanced section of your Jenkins Job.

Normally this should be the default value, but with Jenkins and Maven jobs, [it isn't so](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24655). For those, this property is actually set to `true` unless you set it yourself.

(disclaimer: looked up the exact Jenkins steps from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28684048/365237)).