# How to run pipeline stage only when there are no test failures?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins in a **multi-modular** Maven project and I have three stages in my pipeline: build, test and deploy. I want to be able to **run all unit tests** during `test` stage and, when there are test failures, `deploy` stage **should be skipped**.

For now, I managed to find a workaround (which works as I want it to), but I had to explicitly approve usage of some methods, which are marked by Jenkins as vurnelabilities.

I am wondering if there is any clearer way to achieve my goals?

```
import hudson.tasks.test.AbstractTestResultAction

pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-jdk-8-alpine'
            args '--name maven3 -v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install -DskipTests'
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test --fail-never'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit '**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def AbstractTestResultAction testResultAction = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)
                    if (testResultAction == null) {
                        error("Could not read test results")
                    }
                    def numberOfFailedTests = testResultAction.failCount
                    testResultAction = null
                    if (numberOfFailedTests == null || numberOfFailedTests != 0) {
                        error("Did not deploy. Number of failed tests: " + numberOfFailedTests)
                    }
                    sh 'mvn deploy -DskipTests'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your build stage and Test stage duplicating several things based on the life cycle of Maven which means you should make a single Stage which will do the build and running of unit/integration tests... I would do `mvn --fail-at-end -e -B clean verify` cause I doubt that you need an `mvn install` ... furthermore if your really like to do a deploy than really do a single stage `mvn --fail-at-end -e -B clean deploy` and that's it....Deploy means only artifacts will be transfered to a repository manager ....

Comment: Well, my project is multi-modular and `--fail-at-end` results in skipping tests from modules that depend on the failing module. Which is not what I want it to do, as I need results of all tests in my project.

Answer (score 0):

In your test stage you execute: `mvn test --fail-never`

Now even if you have test failures maven will return with an exit code 0.

Jenkins is checking the exit code. if it is 0 it will continue with the next command.

so get rid of `--fail-never`

Comment: My project has many modules and I strictly want to execute all tests along them.

Comment: One idea i found at [how-to-compile-all-maven-modules-even-if-tests-fail-but-fail-overall-build-if-a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833589/how-to-compile-all-maven-modules-even-if-tests-fail-but-fail-overall-build-if-a) is to first call `mvn test --fail-never` and then `mvn test`. Which isn't very pretty. I think your way by checking the test results of the current build is a good one.

Comment: Another idea maybe worth to try is to set the option `options { skipStagesAfterUnstable() }`. When `junit` is called and there a test failures it should mark the build as unstable.